# Drake - Equations of motion for a walking robot size mismatch

Tags: drake

I'm trying to calculate the equations of motion for a walking robot to constrain its motion in a mathematical program.

M(q) q_ddot + C(q, q_dot) = G(q) + B(q) u + J'(q) lambda

We're basing our implementation on this pre-existing [manipulator equation constraint](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/optimization/manipulator_equation_constraint.cc) with some differences because we're using different decision variables.

The problem we're facing is that there's a mismatch in size between the jacobian matrices and and the rest of the matrices; the jacobian matrix has 31 rows while the rest has 30.This is the same mismatch found between the vector returned by plant.GetPosition and plant.GetVelocities (which can be fixed with MapQDotToVelocity).

What's the recommended way of resolving this size mismatch?

The code we're using to calculate the jacobian:

```py
def Contact_Jacobian(claw_id):
    """Returns the Contact Jacobian"""
    query_object = scene_graph_ad.get_query_output_port().Eval(scene_graph_context_ad)
    inspector = query_object.inspector()
    geometryA_id = Worldbody_id
    geometryB_id = claw_id
    signed_distance_pair = query_object.ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints(geometryA_id, geometryB_id)

    X_AGa = inspector.GetPoseInFrame(signed_distance_pair.id_A)
    p_GaCa = signed_distance_pair.p_ACa
    p_ACa = X_AGa.cast[AutoDiffXd]().multiply(p_GaCa)

    X_BGb = inspector.GetPoseInFrame(signed_distance_pair.id_B)
    p_GbCb = signed_distance_pair.p_BCb
    p_BCb = X_BGb.cast[AutoDiffXd]().multiply(p_GbCb)

    frame_A_id = inspector.GetFrameId(signed_distance_pair.id_A)
    frame_B_id = inspector.GetFrameId(signed_distance_pair.id_B)
    frameA = plant_ad.GetBodyFromFrameId(frame_A_id).body_frame()
    frameB = plant_ad.GetBodyFromFrameId(frame_B_id).body_frame()

    frame_W = plant_ad.world_frame()
    wrt = JacobianWrtVariable.kQDot

    Jv_V_WCa = plant_ad.CalcJacobianTranslationalVelocity(context_ad, wrt, frameA, p_ACa, frame_W, frame_W)
    Jv_V_WCb = plant_ad.CalcJacobianTranslationalVelocity(context_ad, wrt, frameB, p_BCb, frame_W, frame_W)

    return Jv_V_WCa, Jv_V_WCb
```

Comment: As Russ says below, you just need to change your "with respect to" instruction to:
wrt = JacobianWrtVariable.kV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear, the reason for the different dimensions between q and v is because you have a quaternion floating base (7 positions; 6 velocities).

The Jacobian method you are calling can return either the Jacobian with respect to qdot or with respect to v; as you say, these are not the same.

Is it possible that all that needs to change in your code is the value of your wrt variable?  If not, then I’ll need to know how what is actually failing (perhaps so the error message) to help more.